# Scala RDF4J application won't terminate

Tags: scala, sparql, rdf4j

I have been writing a fair amount of Scala + RDF4J over the past several months.  So far so good.

I just wrote this today, and the application won't terminate.  It prints out the requested three triples and the word "done" but doesn't return to a sbt command prompt (or, in Eclipse, the stop button stays red  and hovering over the run button brings up a "already running message")

**What the heck am I doing wrong?**  I have run it against several different endpoints, including a RDF4J server, Virtuoso, and Blazegraph.

My source

```
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryLanguage
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sparql.SPARQLRepository

object sharedMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparqlEndpoint = "https://dbpedia.org/sparql"
    val SparqlRepo = new SPARQLRepository(sparqlEndpoint)
    SparqlRepo.initialize()

    var con = SparqlRepo.getConnection()

    var queryString = "SELECT ?x ?y WHERE { ?x ?p ?y } limit 3 "
    val tupleQuery = con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString)
    var result = tupleQuery.evaluate()

    while (result.hasNext()) { // iterate over the result
      val bindingSet = result.next()
      val valueOfX = bindingSet.getValue("x")
      val valueOfY = bindingSet.getValue("y")
      val toPrint = valueOfX + " -> " + valueOfY
      println(toPrint)
    }

    result.close
    con.close

    println("done")
  }
}
```

My build.sbt

```
name := "tripleStoreTesting"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.0"
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.5" % "runtime",
    "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.1",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test",
    "org.eclipse.rdf4j" % "rdf4j-runtime" % "2.2.2",
    "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2"
)
mainClass := Some("sharedMain")
```

Comment: Maybe adding `sparqlRepo.shutDown()` to the end helps? Scaladoc: http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/2.0/org/eclipse/rdf4j/repository/base/AbstractRepository.html#shutDown--

Comment: Yes, adding `SparqlRepo.shutDown()` after `con.close` does the job.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkMiller make your comment an answer - I'm sure others will stumble over this in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AKSW suggested, I haven't closed or shut down everything I have opened, started, initialized, etc.

```
// Scala code snippet, 
// starting with my program's last interaction with the triplestore

while (result.hasNext) { // iterate over the result
  val bindingSet = result.next
  val valueOfX = bindingSet.getValue("x")
  val valueOfY = bindingSet.getValue("y")
  val toPrint = valueOfX + " -> " + valueOfY
  println(toPrint)
}

result.close
con.close

// ADD THIS for proper application termination
SparqlRepo.shutDown
```

In addition to the [JavaDocs AKSW posted](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/2.0/org/eclipse/rdf4j/repository/base/AbstractRepository.html#shutDown--), the [RDF4J](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/) programming tutorial does a pretty good job of emphasizing the many things that need to be closed properly.

- connections
- result iterators
- statement iterators
- input streams
- naturally, files

It just doesn't specifically mention shutting down `SPARQLRepository` instances.